# Error: Tables could not be created. (Collabtive php)

Tags: php, mysql

Error: Tables could not be created.
I have created a database, and I have given all privelages.
but still am not able to login to collabtive module.
I am fed up with it, but I dont wanna give up.
I have tried all possible methods, but dint work. Stackoverflow is the best I know.
Kindly help !!!

Comment: Please add much more detail about what you are doing where and what tools you are using. (I don't know the tool you are referring to, and I expect many others don't either.)

Comment: Usually it also lists a reason i.e. "MyISAM not supported".  Did it list a reason when it said tables couldn't be created?

Comment: Also provide error messages if you get any and whether you are trying to connect locally etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open install.php within the collabtive source code and replace

TYPE=MyISAM

with

ENGINE=MyISAM

http://collabtive.o-dyn.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6536

Comment: @hesh Glad I could help.  Since it worked, would you mind selecting this as the answer to your question?  Thanks

Comment: sorry was away for some time.